# passing in int* for int[][] C/C++

Tags: c++, c, pointers, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int foo(int bar[3][3]){
    return bar[1][1];
}

int main(){
    int* bar = (int*) malloc(9 * sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        bar[i] = i;
    }
    int test = foo(bar);
    printf("%d\n", test);
}
```

Compiling this with C gives a warning

```
warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int *' to parameter of type 'int (*)[3]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    int test = foo(bar);
```

But still outputs the expected result of 4 (Although I imagine the warning is a sign of UB)

Compiling with g++ gives an error

```
error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
    int test = foo(bar);
note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int *' to 'int (*)[3]' for 1st argument
int foo(int bar[3][3]){
```

I cannot change the function signature of bar but would like to just pass in a simple pointer to the array. What is the simplest typecast/change of code that would make this compile with no UB with g++. This is for code that I am generating with a Python script while looking at the function signature of bar so the simpler the solution the better. (This is just an example)

Comment: do you mean the function signature of `foo`? `bar` is the (optional) name of `foo`'s parameter (and also a local of `main`)

Comment: An array decays to a pointer, but not the other way round.

Comment: Please, please, *please* stop using C-style arrays (*and* `malloc`). Just use `std::array` or `std::vector`. *Please*.

Comment: @JesperJuhl this code seems to be compiled with both C and C++ compilers, so STL pretty much isn't an option.

Comment: @Ayxan It's tagged "c++". I just go by that.

Comment: @JesperJuhl tagged with C *and* C++

Comment: @Ayxan it also says "compiling with g++".

Comment: @WeatherVane yes. As I said, with a C compiler and  a C++ compiler. C compiler compiles the code with a warning while C++ rejects it

Answer (score 4):

Quick and dirty fix:

```
foo(reinterpret_cast<int(*)[3]>(bar)); // C++ only
foo((int(*)[3])bar); // C and C++
```

Replaces the implicit cast present in C language with an explicit one to let the C++ compiler know you are intending to circumvent the type-system.

Comment: Any way of getting around having to have the 3 in the brackets as well? Easily doable but a little extra work for my regular expressions.

Comment: No, although I don't think my concern is addressable. I will have to read the dimensions from the function signature one way or another it seems in order to compile. Thanks for the help tho, this will work!

Comment: @HashBr0wn C++ does not have variable length arrays, but it has `std::vector` and `Eigen::Map` etc.

Comment: @HashBr0wn how about https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rroK9q

Comment: Im just going with your C and C++ fix

Answer (score 3):

Without dynamic memory allocation:

```c
int main(void) {
   int bar[3][3];
   for (int i=0; i<9; ++i) {
      bar[i / 3][i % 3] = i;
   }

   printf("%d\n", foo(bar));
}
```

With: (C)

```c
int main(void) {
   int (*bar)[3] = malloc(3 * sizeof(int[3]));

   for (int i=0; i<9; ++i) {
      bar[i / 3][i % 3] = i;
   }

   printf("%d\n", foo(bar));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is the simplest typecast/change of code that would make this compile with no UB with g++

```
int main(){
    int bar[3][3];
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        bar[i / 3][i % 3] = i;
    }
    int test = foo(bar);
    printf("%d\n", test);
}
```

Works in both C++ and C